# HTML: target="_blank" for a drop-down list

Tags: javascript, html

**Problem:** to open a new window with the select -option

```
<form onsubmit="return handleSubmit()" target="_blank" method="get" name="moduleForm" id="moduleForm">
<font size=2 face = verdana color= #0000ff ><b>Search</b></font>

    <select name="allSelect" id="allSelect">
    <optgroup label="Historical">
    <option value="http://www.something.com/cse?cx=0000000000000&sa=Search&q=">Open in a new window 1</option>
    <option value="http://www.google.com/cse?cx=0000000000000000A-cmjrngmyku&ie=UTF-8&sa=Search&q=">Open in a new window 2</option>
    </optgroup>
    </select>

<input type="text" name="allQuery" id="allQuery" size="22" />
<input type="submit" value=" Go " />
```

**Question:** How can I open the content to a new window with a select-box?

Comment: What does `handleSubmit()` do?

Comment: Gumbo: Please, see an example here:  http://savedbythegoog.appspot.com/?id=ag5zYXZlZGJ5dGhlZ29vZ3ISCxIJU2F2ZWRDb2RlGNawvAEM.

Comment: _gel(id)  : A wrapper around the JavaScript document.getElementById() function from google gadgets. 

moduleForm is only the name of the <form> element. To find the right <form>, getElementById is udes.

Comment: @Martin K.: Very interesting thing there. Do you mean "Unix Desktop Environments" in the sentence "To find the right <form>, getElementById is udes. "? I cannot see the relation to the topic, wondering...

Comment: @SimpleThings: That was my reply to the other question you opened (has been delted)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify [your `handleSubmit` function](http://savedbythegoog.appspot.com/?id=ag5zYXZlZGJ5dGhlZ29vZ3ISCxIJU2F2ZWRDb2RlGNawvAEM) as follows:

```
function handleSubmit()
{
    var form = _gel("moduleForm"),
        elm = _gel("allQuery"),
        selectElm = _gel("allSelect");
    if (elm != "" && selectElm != "") {
        var query = elm.value;
        var searchUrl = selectElm.value;
        if (query != "" && searchUrl != "") {
            searchUrl += escape(query);
            window.open(searchUrl, form.target || "_blank");
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: How did you know about the parts 'form = _gel("moduleForm");' and 'form.target || "_blank")'? I cannot even google them.

Comment: Great thanks for solving the problem. Sorry for being straightforward, but how on earth you you knew about the "moduleForm"-thing? It amazes me. Hope to be as good as you some day. Thanks again.

Comment: That’s just the form’s name/ID in your example code. And after the `_gel()` function is also used for the input field `allQuery` and select field `allSelect`, I assumed that this function uses that value either as name or ID. And `form.target || "_blank"` is just an OR expression that returns the value of the first alternation that’s can evaluated to *true*. So if `form.target` would be undefined, `"_blank"` would be used as default value.

Comment: Can you clarify the sentence "That’s just the form’s name/ID in your example code."? I cannot find it from the source code.

Comment: Sure. First line: `<form […]` **`name="moduleForm" id="moduleForm">`**

Comment: Gumbo: Please, see my view: http://pastebin.com/d6bfd694. There is no such line. I tested it with Opera, Firefox and Safari. I suppose you mean this as my example: http://savedbythegoog.appspot.com/?id=ag5zYXZlZGJ5dGhlZ29vZ3ISCxIJU2F2ZWRDb2RlGNawvAEM. I cannot see no such line.

Comment: The form’s start tag is missing in that example document. But it’s in the example code in your question.

Comment: Solved. Thank you Gumbo! I did not notice my mistake in the example. Sorry for the inconvience.

Answer (score 1):

You can open your links by window.open() :

```
<select name="allSelect" id="allSelect">
<optgroup label="Historical">
<option value="http://www.something.com/cse?cx=0000000000000&sa=Search&q=">Open in a new window 1</option>
<option value="http://www.google.com/cse?cx=0000000000000000A-cmjrngmyku&ie=UTF-8&sa=Search&q=">Open in a new window 2</option>
</optgroup>
</select>

<input type="button" 
    value="open in a new window" 
    onclick="window.open(document.getElementById(allSelect).value);" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Give a look to the [window.open](http://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Window.open) function.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that your page should be usable without scripting, so I'd suggest implementing a fallback mechanism: The form should call a server-side script which responds with a `30x` status and a `Location` header.

The client-side would look like this:

```
<form action="path-to-redirection-script" method="GET" target="_blank"
 onsubmit="window.open(this.elements['foo'].value); return false;">
 <select name="foo" size="1">
  <option value="http://google.com">google</option>
 </select>
 <input type="submit" value="go">
</form>
```

Also, remember that `target="_blank"` / `window.open()` [is often evil](http://www.trilithium.com/johan/2005/03/target-blank/).

Comment: Can you make it such a way that you run the server-side script if and only if the user has JS disabled? If I understand right, the script will always be fetched once per visit.

Comment: The solution to my question in this comment seems to be here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/121203/how-to-detect-if-javascript-is-disabled/125775#125775

Comment: I opened a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1122609/javascript-for-a-form-on-the-server-side