# Detect if Javascript is enabled?

Tags: javascript, jsp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to detect if JavaScript is disabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121203/how-to-detect-if-javascript-is-disabled)

Is it possible to detect whether javascript has been disabled if so redirect to another page?
My application is being developed with JSPs, as I am using a lot of fancy javascript stuff in my application.
Thanks in Advance
Dean

Comment: Found another answer to this question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/121203/how-to-detect-if-javascript-is-disabled > "noscript" tag IS the most semanticly
> accurate way to specify non-javascript
> content - and rather then detecting if
> javascript is disabled, detect if it's
> enabled. So show the "you need
> javascript to properly use my site"
> message by default, but hide it with a
> javascript function immediately
> onLoad. – matt lohkamp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the <noscript> tag:
http://www.boutell.com/newfaq/creating/detectjs.html

Answer (score 0):

Know this is an old thread, but just thought it add my own solution. I have javascript controlled `<div>` and on a browser where javascript is disabled, none of these are show so:

1. Have a standard `<div>` in center of page saying “**please enable javascript to view or click here for non javascript page**”
2. Set the `z-value` to `-1`
3. Have all javascript controlled `<div>` and set with a white/whatever `background` and a `z-index` value to 0 or higher

The javascript controlled `<div>` will cover the message if enabled, and show it if not.

Hope that this gives one or two of you a few ideas. Although this was specifically for my site, you may find that thinking out the box may help you too.