# Check if javascript is enabled on all (most) browsers?

Tags: javascript, browser

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to detect if JavaScript is disabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121203/how-to-detect-if-javascript-is-disabled)

I have a website which uses a lot of JavaScript.

I need to check if JavaScript is disabled, then redirect user to a certain "enable JavaScript please" page.

I need to do this before everything else is loaded on the index.html page of my website.

Does anybody have a way of doing this and be sure that it works on the majority of browsers?

Thanks

If you need more input, let me know...

Comment: Exact duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/121203/how-to-detect-if-javascript-is-disabled

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<noscript><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=YOUR_URL_HERE"></noscript>
```

Comment: I'm told that this doesn't work with several blockers, where `noscript` elements are simply ignored

Comment: what do you mean with "blockers"?

Comment: JavaScript blockers, that try to prevent running spyware and the like.