# Detecting Javascript enabled?

Tags: javascript, codeigniter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to detect if JavaScript is disabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121203/how-to-detect-if-javascript-is-disabled)

I need to detect if JS is enabled for my ajax page refresh content, I know I can use noscript tags but it doesn’t work too well in the controller, can anyone suggest what I can do? Thanks

Comment: [Unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) would be better and easier I guess. Meaning: Build your website first so that it works without JavaScript. Then add JavaScript to enable Ajax functionality.

Comment: Perhaps you could tell us how `noscript` is an issue with CodeIgnighter's controller; otherwise people are going to read right past that and close this and/or say "use `noscript`" despite your having clearly said you knew about it.

Comment: Please consider the other questions on this subject by searching using the search box at the top of the screen. If `<noscript>` is your only option, and it isn't working, feel free to post another question related specifically to that issue. :o)