# How to know javascript is enabled in client side?

Tags: php, javascript, client-side

I am developing a web application such a way that my codes dynamically generating JavaScript functions using php. If JavaScript is disabled in my client side, my application will not work properly. So I should inform my clients that JavaScript is not enabled in their browser. Is it possible to check using php code?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/121203/how-to-detect-if-javascript-is-disabled

Comment: check the url [How to detect if JavaScript is disabled?][1] that is similar to your 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/q/121203/1035257

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<noscript> Please enable js</noscript>
```

Comment: Consider that the noscript-element won't work in a XHTML5-Document.

Answer (score 2):

Nope, not directly since the PHP code will be evaluated at a server level. It is only possible at clientside, using the `<noscript />` HTML tag.

You could try the `get_browser` method (see [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php)), but it is not 100% reliable.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible directly using PHP - the solution by stecb is a client side solution which will display a message if javascript is not enabled.