# Use Jquery selector to add a HTML tag

Tags: jquery, html

I have a HTML with with a paragraph and a contact form. When the browser has JavaScript disabled I want to show contact form and  paragraph of text.

Otherwise, I want to show the contact  button, which users can click and the form shows up.

Comment: Is it important for the contact button to be hidden when JS is disabled?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/121203/how-to-detect-if-javascript-is-disabled please refer this for javascript enable/disable detection

Comment: @tracy yes coz, for the browser with js enabled, the form will show up by default. Only it's hidden when js is disabled.

Answer (score 1):

Set the button's style to `display:none;`

If javascript is enabled, hide the form by default and show the button.

Then when they click the contact button, show it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#buttonID").show();
  $("#formID").hide();
  $("#buttonID").click(function(){
    $("#formID").show();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<span id="formAndParagraph">
    <p id="Paragraph">lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum </p>
    <form id="Contact">
        Name: <input type="text"><br>
        Comment: <input type="text"><br>
    </form>
</span>
<input type="button" id="Button" value="Click me" onclick="$('#formAndParagraph').show();" style="display:none">
<script>
$('#formAndParagraph').hide();
$('#Button').show();
</script>
```

[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/xT73k/)

Answer (score 0):

Ok :) So here's my solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/tracyfu/Sj5cy/

And here's what it does:

1. I set the `#contact-button` css to `display: none;` so that it's automatically hidden whether or not JS is present. This way if JS is disabled, the button doesn't show up.
2. In the JS, I show `#contact-button`, then I hide `#contact-form`. JQuery will only work when JS is enabled anyway, so what this does is show the button and hide the form for people who have JS. For people who have JS disabled, the form is not affected and will show up like usual.
3. I added a `click` event to the button to show the form.

The goal of this solution is so that there isn't a button if JS is disabled.