# No javascript detect in JSP page

Tags: javascript, jsp, detect, noscript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to detect if JavaScript is disabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121203/how-to-detect-if-javascript-is-disabled)

My question is how to detect in the server side web application that there is no javascript enabled?
I know the tag  but I want to do it in servlet or with pure java. I do not want to use noscript tag 
because I have to redirect the page if there is not javascript enalbed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I do not want to use the check with  cookies for javascript

Comment: From the accepted answer in the linked question: "There isn't a good way to perform server-side JavaScript detection."

Comment: ok so how to make redirect if i use noscript tag?

Answer (score 0):

OK I found a way to do it.
Make two div tags.
The first one will contain the noscript text
and the second one will contain the main content of the page.
With javascript you just have to hide the one div and to show the other. If there is no javascript the div with the text won't dissapear and the other won't show.