# Firefox: javascript disabled

Tags: javascript

does somebody exactly know what informations firefox sends to tell the application that javascript is disabled? I´ll need this for automation purpose: I have to imitate a browser with js disabled.

Comment: I don't think it is sending any information at all. All "JS disabled" detection tricks I know use workarounds to detect its absence... where do you get the idea from that information is sent?

Comment: I´m not that familiar with js. I just realized that some websites see the cURL client as a client with javascript ENabled. I thought, there would be something sent to check the js support. But Pekka seems to be right: There are just a few workarounds, so to imitate a browser with no js support i have to go deeper into code and find out, which workaround is used there.

Comment: If you want to see what happens when visit a site use fiddler.

Comment: This may not be the most advanced question, but I don't see why it deserves 3 downvotes?

Comment: Somewhat related, but not the same: [How to detect if JavaScript is disabled?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/121203/how-to-detect-if-javascript-is-disabled)

Answer (score 1):

If a browser has JavaScript disabled, it:

1. Will not process JavaScript `script` elements (won't execute the code within them if they're inline, won't download or execute the referenced files if they use `src`).
2. **Will** render the markup contents within `<noscript>...</noscript>` blocks in the document's markup.
3. Will not fire any event handlers hooked up with DOM0 attributes like `onclick` and such.

I don't believe there's any information sent to the server to tell it the browser has JavaScript disabled, e.g., there's no difference in the `accepts` header or similar.

Comment: In addition: won't fire any JavaScript events and thus won't call any JavaScript event listeners when used in `onEVENT` attributes.