# How to identify if javascript is disabled by browser

Tags: javascript

I was puzzled with a question. Many browsers like Internet Explorer allows to disable the javascript.

How do I check through whether the user's Browser has disabled javascript or not?

Comment: What are you using the check for? It doesn't make sense to check if a user's browser has Javascript enabled, since that would require a programming language like Javascript to be enabled. You could use some `noscript` trickery though.

Comment: Why do you need to detect?  If you are trying to change CSS, a common way is to have a class on your body, `nojs` or something, and then remove it with JavaScript.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/121203/how-to-detect-if-javascript-is-disabled

Answer (score 2):

An approach that e.g. modernizr uses is that you set a class `no-js` and modernizr then removes that class after finishing.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to pdeurstler's answer, there is an old school way.

It is tad old school but, `<noscript>...</noscript>` detects JavaScript being disabled and executes the embed HTML.

Comment: +1 should I use script in noscript tag? Is there any example?

Comment: @Umesh - You just made my day - using a `script` tag in a `noscript` tag. Genius bro. No. Don't do it. Think before you talk.

Comment: @AaditMShah, +1 Forgive me yar.. but I didn't get it.

Comment: @Umesh, Ha Ha.. please do not.

Answer (score 1):

A common solution is to the `meta` tag in conjunction with `noscript` to refresh the page and notify the server when JavaScript is disabled, like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <noscript>
            <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; /?javascript=false">
        </noscript>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        <title></title>
    </head>
</html>
```

In the above example when JavaScript is disabled the browser will redirect to the home page of the web site in `0` seconds. In addition it will also send the parameter `javascript=false` to the server.

A server side script such as node.js or PHP can then parse the parameter and come to know that JavaScript is disabled. It can then send a special non-JavaScript version of the web site to the client.

Answer (score 0):

Just have some text that says you need javascript to use the site, then onload destroy that text with javascript.