# Enable and disable browser JavaScript option by using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

After applying client side validation on page, if browser JavaScript option has been disabled then all page validation/function are dead. So I need a JavaScript function, that automatically enables and disables JavaScript of any browser, it should run on my page and work on every browser.

Comment: maybe throw in some code first? :)

Comment: There is no way you can get the browser settings be changed via scriping. But you can detect it. Please see : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/121203/how-to-detect-if-javascript-is-disabled

Comment: Don't you think it could be a little security issue?

Comment: @Anubi: No i m looking for enabled js option by js function.if browser js option disabled,then it will enabled js option and set client side validation.

Comment: Btw, that's one of the reasons why always need server side validation. Client side validation should only be used for improved UX, but it's not a security measure.

Comment: @Abhishek I understand what you want to do. The security problem is that you cannot allow a web page to change user settings on a browser!

Comment: @Anubi:no more option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you should do is detect that javascript is disabled and degrade your application to do validation in server side instead of client side.

Comment: :Only change status of checkbox disabled to enabled,that's it?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: If i apply client side validation on my html page and if my mozilla browser js option disabled then, if i write some js function to enabled that checkbox,then is it possible or not?

Comment: No man, NO! It isn't possible! As I said, if js is disabled, you have to validate at SERVER SIDE. Forget about changing browser options, you can't!

Answer (score 3):

Your requirement is impossible to achieve. Among other considerations, how do you pretend to enable javascript in a browser where javascript is disabled using javascript?

Comment: Is it possible to change browser setting?for javascript enabled.

Comment: @Abhishek: No it is not (as already mentioned a couple of times).