# Is display:table a perfectly acceptable method for equal height columns?

Tags: css, html, responsive-design

I'm building a responsive design and I need two equal height columns. I don't want to rely on JavaScript, and I would like whitespace in between the columns for extra legibility.

I've made two layouts; [one using `display:table;`](http://jsfiddle.net/Uzv5Q/) and [the other using `float` and `position`](http://jsfiddle.net/EFTD9/). The problem here is that I can't seem to get the latter method to have whitespace in between the columns, while the table method works fine in this aspect.

Because of this, I'd ideally like to use the table method, but I was wondering if this was an acceptable way to achieve an equal height column design for a webite that will utilize modern web standards?

### Research on CSS Table Support

From a little research, I've found the `display:table` method to be compatible with the following browsers (by supporting [all of the necessary CSS properties](http://jsfiddle.net/9y7w6/3/) that I will need):

- Chrome 1+
- Firefox 1+
- Internet Explorer 8+
- Safari 1.2+
- Opera 7+
- Android 2.1+
- iOS 3.2+
- BlackBerry 6+
- Internet Explorer Mobile 9+ (Windows Phone 7+)
- Opera Mobile 10+
- Opera Mini 5+
- Nokia Browser 7.3+ (Symbian Anna)
- Nokia Browser 8.5+ (MeeGo 1.2 on Nokia N9)

A Google search for *"Is CSS display table a good idea?"* reveals several articles which are against the CSS table method, In particular, [this article](http://2002-2012.mattwilcox.net/archive/entry/id/1030/) which I've been reading. I'm aware that it's several years old, so what exactly is the overall acceptance of this method nowadays, considering the level of browser support I've found above?

### Notes

- I want to drop support for Internet Explorer 7 and below, and I'm not sure about Firefox 3 and below (open to suggestions).
- Also, I would generally want to test in older browsers/browser versions, but my laptop doesn't have enough RAM to run a virtual machine and downloading the necessary files would take hours on an inconstant 10-20 Mb/s connection. Are there any alternatives (all other computers in the house don't have older browsers either)?

Thanks!

### References

- My own testing in Chrome 30, Firefox 24/25, Safari 5.1.7, Opera 17, IE 10/11, IE8/IE9 using IE10 developer tools and Android 4.1.1.
- W3Schools CSS Reference - [display](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp); [border-collapse](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_tab_border-collapse.asp); [border-spacing](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_tab_border-spacing.asp); [overflow](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp)
- MDN CSS Reference - [display](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display); [border-collapse](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-collapse); [border-spacing](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-spacing); [overflow](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow)
- [QuirksMode CSS Reference](http://quirksmode.org/css/) (scroll down to 'Index' section)
- MSDN CSS Compatibility in IE6-10 - [display](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ie/ms530751.aspx); [border-collapse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ie/hh781508.aspx#border_and_layout); [border-spacing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ie/hh781508.aspx#border_and_layout); [overflow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ie/hh781508.aspx#positioning)
- [Can I Use... CSS Tables](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-table)

Comment: Tabular design layouts in HTML are hackish. CSS tables as you are using, via `display:table` seem perfectly acceptable.. I see no reason as to why you shouldn't do it this way. 1+ for a researched, and well asked question, we need more of those.

Comment: The main disadvantage of them is the redundant code needed, so if you enjoy lowered stress levels over pedantry, go for it! :)

Comment: Don't forget about inline-blocks and [flexboxes](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/), they're often a good solution to floats too. Also as far as vertical alignment, often times line-height can acheive the same effect as a parented:Display:table and a child:display:table;vertical-alignment: middle.

Comment: @mulquin I was hoping that I could bypass at least some of the coding by missing out defined `table-row` elements, since the spec states that the browser should automatically fill that in, if it's missing. For example, if I use `table` and `table-cell`, and intentionally miss out `table-row`, the browser should insert it for me (at least according to what I've been reading). Is it bad to use this concept?

Comment: @DylRicho: That's perfectly acceptable, as long as the anonymous boxes that are filled in will work correctly with your layout. For example, if you had a table box, with two children that are table cells, the anonymous row box that is created will always contain both of them.

Comment: @JoshC I don't really see the difference between html and css tables. All an element is, is browser default css collection. I think both are a bit hackish.

Comment: I'm thinking about how this may be "Primarily opinion based", but decided not to flag because a question about deprecation isn't. The wording is pretty unspecific. Is it deprecated? Good(isn) question, I believe the answer is no. Is it acceptable? That will be "Primarily opinion based".

Comment: @Dude I always seem to ask opinion-based questions here...

Comment: @BoltClock From the testing I've done, it does appear to work fine with my layout, so that's all good. Is there anything problematic about [this layout](http://jsfiddle.net/hAST4/1/)?

Comment: @DylRicho Really! [Yeah](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19744045/should-i-use-the-new-html5-semantic-elements)...

Comment: @Dude So you're telling me Stackoverflow is only for yes-or-no questions? Pretty lame if you can't even discuss different techniques to certain situations, if you ask me.

Comment: @DylRicho: That seems fine (other than the missing `</ul>` end tags). And Stack Overflow isn't just for yes-or-no questions (some y/n questions are subjective too). It just doesn't like discussions and prefers technical answers that are clear-cut right or wrong.

Comment: @DylRicho An acceptable question is "What is wrong? I have `asdf(function(){}).foo.onclick.a.b.c()` and it's printing `hello` instead of `hi`. This isn't yes/no, but it also isn't as much of a preference or taste thing.

Comment: @Dude I merely wanted to ask other web developers, what they thought about the CSS table method for equal height columns, since I've seen many different examples, and this one worked well for me. Sure, I know it's opinion-based, but if multiple web developers with high reputation give it the all-clear, that's persuasive enough for me. I don't know if you realize this, but there aren't many websites where you can interact with other web developers in this manor. I'm not trying to go against Stackoverflow's rules or anything, I'm just wanting advise for my future decisions. :)

Comment: @BoltClock Oops, that was simply something I overlooked in Notepad++. [All fixed now](http://jsfiddle.net/hAST4/2/). Thanks for the input!

Comment: @DylRicho Google "ask a web developer forum" and yippee! You have 26 million results.

Comment: I already have enough online accounts; I don't need any more, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is, take a look at [Bootstrap](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/dist/css/bootstrap.css) 's source code, they grid this way

In your browser look for

```
display: table;
```

and you will see how they implement it in the .row