# How to detect if JavaScript is disabled using Meteor.com

Tags: meteor, javascript

When using Meteor.com anyone know how to detect if the browser's JavaScript is disabled...

AND show a message to the end user in the browser window, i.e "Turn on JavaScript."

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to detect if JavaScript is disabled?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/121203/how-to-detect-if-javascript-is-disabled)

Comment: The usual <noscript> doesn't work with the Meteor.com framework. What will work to detect if JavaScript is disabled?

Answer (score 3):

I assume that you have a `layout.html` or at least a `main.html` that contains at least a `<head>`.

A trick is to place `<noscript>` *in the `<head>`* instead of the `<body>`.

Meteor does not render everything in JS. There are some stuff that get's rendered in an *initial page*, proof of which can be seen in *View Source* (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>).

Comment: No, Meteor uses handlebars and it's all JavaScript driven via the Meteor server. Here's a thread on Google groups with more info, but no answer.

Comment: @CarlFoggin I had a meteor setup when I did this, and it did work with JS disabled.

Comment: @CarlFoggin the template parser in meteor only takes everything thats not in `<head></head>` when it converts it to javascript. So this should work fine.

Comment: It simply does NOT work, btw, I'm using: $ meteor --version
Release 0.6.6.3 -- I tried <noscript> in the <head>, the <body> in both my main template and in /.meteor/local/build/programs/client/app.html. I'm running in dev mode on my local PC. Here's the link to the thread on Google Groups: [link](http://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/meteor-talk/2q4qiP2v6Bs)

Comment: @CarlFoggin My meteor is also 0.6.6.3, and it did work in my setup. However, I use [generator-meteor](https://npmjs.org/package/generator-meteor) from [Yeoman](http://yeoman.io/), where it comes with [Iron-Router](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router). I use a [global layout](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router#global-router-configuration) where my `<head>` is defined. This might be the case.

Comment: @CarlFoggin The head tag should *not* be inside a template tag.

Comment: @CeesTimmerman Sure, but this answer is a hack. And browser is kind enough to find duplicate `<head>` tags and puts their content in one `<head>` - the one that's not in body. Besides, **this answer is 2 years old**. Meteor was 0.6 that time. Things may have changed.

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer I'm using the latest Meteor in Chrome, and head tags were not merged. Only `<head><noscript>Please enable JavaScript.</noscript></head><template name="index">...</template>` worked for me.

Comment: @CeesTimmerman I guess that's what the answer meant. I should have been clearer :D.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the latest Meteor in Chrome, and head tags were not merged. Only this worked for me:

```
<head>
    <noscript>Please enable JavaScript.</noscript>
</head>

<template name="index">
...
</template>
```

Answer (score 1):

I just used this and it really worked like a charm

```
<head>
<noscript>
<style>
body {font-size: 32px;text-align: center;line-height: 100vh;}
body:after {content: "Please enable JavaScript";}
</style>
</noscript>
</head>
```