# CSS detect browser support javascript

Tags: html, css

If possibility to checking in CSS detect browser support javascript ?
or set other CSS Media Queries for browser not support javascript ?

Comment: All browsers support JS. Are you asking to detect if it's turned off?

Comment: css alone doesn't detect if js is turned on. You need to use also js

Comment: e.g: google boot or js is turned off

Comment: Modernizr.js 
.no-js .tabs-content > .content {display: block !important;}

result: <html class="no-js" >

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The common way is to add a class called no-js to your , e.g.

```
<head class='no-js'>
```

then as your first line of JS, remove the class.

To keep it simple, in jQuery you'd then write:

```
$("head").removeClass("no-js");
```

If you are using plain JS, you need to parse the class attribute and remove just the no-js bit, else if you add further classes later you will wipe them out with a naive approach.

You can then write CSS like:

```
.message {
    display:none;
}

.no-js .message {
    display:block;
}
```

If you wanted to show an element with class message only to people with JS disabled.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it without javascript. You have to use ... HTML !

There is a tag for that : [noscript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/noscript)

**Summary** :

> The HTML `<noscript>` Element defines a section of html to be inserted if a script type on the page is unsupported or if scripting is currently turned off in the browser.

**Example** :

```
<noscript>
    <!-- this content will be display if no js -->
</noscript>
```

In your case, I think you will need something like this :

```
<noscript>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/nojs.css" />
</noscript>
```

if you want more info about it, [this topic on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121203/how-to-detect-if-javascript-is-disabled) is pretty good.