# what, if browser has javascript disabled, ( AngularJS)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have learned angular.js, and it's awesome , i'm impressed. i want to use it in my website, but what if our some of user has disabled JavaScript on there browser, they should still gonna see my website content ?????. i'll appreciate your help.

Comment: how to handle situations in which users have javascript disabled: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22256371/how-to-handle-javascript-being-disabled-in-angularjs

Answer (score 5):

In most cases when js is required, you should add **noscript** which will be displayed when js is disabled. In that tag you need to warn user that he/she should enable js.

Comment: +1 Or add to `<html>` class `.noscript` and `JavaScript` should firstly delete that. If it stays, `JS` was not loaded.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to other answer, I am quoting from Angular book:

> 1. Not everyone’s browser supports JavaScript. Let everyone see all of your content and use your app without needing to execute code in the
>      browser.
>
> The world has changed since these concepts were born. Point #1 is no
>   longer true for any interesting population. If you’re running a
>   browser without JavaScript, you’re rele‐ gated to sites created in the
>   1990s

Answer (score 0):

Or make a div with a warning/notice text (maybe in center of page), and hide that div in js (first thing in your code)

So, if the user does not have js enabled, they will see the nice warning