# How can I hide a button if JavaScript is disabled?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a website that allows users to create new content and I use javascript as a way to check for spam. If user has javascript turned off how can I hide or disable the **post** search button

```
<input type="submit" name="submitmee" id="creatingpost" value="Post" />
```

Is there a combination of if statements or noscripts that I can use. I have seen some examples online but they all redirect user, im trying to do something like

```
if(javascript== off)
{
    /* please turn on javascript */
}
else
{
    /* show button */
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect if JavaScript is disabled?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/121203/how-to-detect-if-javascript-is-disabled)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just use a `noscript` tag, in your head that is only loaded when javascript is disabled.

### HTML

```
<noscript>
    <style type="text/css">
         #creatingpost {
           display: none; 
         }

         #noJsBanner
         {
            display: block;
         }
    </style>
</noscript>
```

Check this [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/r2kVA/2/) with JavaScript disabled.

Answer (score 1):

Why not show the "no JS" version by default and toggle it with JavaScript (that will obviously only run if JS is enabled)?

HTML:

```html
<div class="js-show">
    <input type="Submit" value="Go!" />
</div>
<div class="js-hide">
    <p>Please switch JavaScript on.</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.js-show
{
    display: "none";
}
```

JavaScript (jQuery):

```
$(function() {
    $('.js-hide').hide();
    $('.js-show').show();
});
```

[Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/WE8DP/)

Alternatively, you could place a "no-js" class on the `html` element and swap it for "js" on `document.ready`, then style things with these classes accordingly.

Either of these approaches gives you a flexible way of creating JS-free alternatives for features across your entire site with only a couple of lines of code.