# Dropdown menu - what language?

Tags: javascript, css

I'd like to make a dropdown menu for my website, but not sure what language is best to use, since both js and css have the hover option.

Comment: Check out js, and particularly a library called jQueryUI. http://jqueryui.com/menu/

Comment: JQuery's animations are probably the best, in my opinion. If you want just simple dropdowns, use CSS.

Comment: I was thinking what happens if JS is not enabled on the client. What happens if I make it in JS and that happens?

Comment: @GeorgeIrimiciuc, you can check if js in enabled and take appropriate action: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/121203/how-to-detect-if-javascript-is-disabled

Comment: You can do it in pure css. Take a look : http://line25.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-pure-css-dropdown-menu

Comment: @GeorgeIrimiciuc, you're going to develop a menu-driven page that doesn't use javascript anywhere else on the page? C'mon man. You're going to be using js somewhere on the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The benefits of css over javascript are

- Will work if people have js turned off  (not many these days, I know)
- Less likely to break if other scripts on the page are invalid
- Less code (especially if you intend to use a library like jquery for that single purpose)
- Tidier code - generally a javascript would be a mix of css and js - css would be in one place.

Javascript can add pretty animations (as can modern css tbh), but if it is not also adding a usability benefit, then I'd go with pure css whenever possible.

Comment: An exception can be made, however, if a nice library exists or you want to have more control over the list and its functions. Ultimately, it depends on what you're trying to do, but I'd take CSS over JS usually for said reasons.