# Detection of javascript disable on a browser for a website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, c

Sometime ago i disable javascript on my google chrome browser, and think how the website owner will detect if a user is disable javascript on that website, and i search on google and found answer of this question on stackoverflow. Here is the Link : [click to show question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121203/how-to-detect-if-javascript-is-disabled) .

After that i wrapped our all content of a page in the class `pagecontainer`  of the body tag something like this :

```
<body class="pagecontainer">
    <noscript>
        <style type="text/css">
            .pagecontainer {display:none;}
        </style>
        <div class="noscriptmsg">
        You don't have javascript enabled.  Good luck with that.
        </div>
    </noscript>
    //all page content is here
</body>
```

after that i disable javascript for this page, and tries to run this page, but i could't get the message which is wrapped within `noscriptmsg` class. So plz help us to give the message which is given in the `noscriptmsg` class if the user disable the javascript for this page.

Answer (score 2):

Your CSS in the `<noscript>` block makes the entire `<body>` be hidden, and your `<noscript>` tag is part of the `<body>`.

You could change it to something like this:

```
<body>
    <noscript>
        <style type="text/css">
            .pagecontainer {display:none;}
        </style>
        <div class="noscriptmsg">
        You don't have javascript enabled.  Good luck with that.
        </div>
    </noscript>
    <section class=pagecontainer>
      //all page content is here
    </section>
</body>
```

An alternative is that you can put a `<meta>` tag in your `<noscript>` block to redirect the browser to your "please enable JavaScript" page. That way your normal pages don't have to worry about it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <noscript>
      <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://your.domain/noscript.html">
    </noscript>
```

Comment: Yes...becuase i also want to hide our all content if a user is disabled javascirpt for this page.

Comment: @ManoharKumar right, but if a parent element is `display: none` then all children are also hidden.