# How to disable a website if javascript is disabled

Tags: javascript, php, html

Like "**Facebook**", I want to disable all of my website content if "JavaScript" is disabled. When JavaScript is disabled Facebook only shows a message .

> "JavaScript Required We're sorry, but Facebook doesn't work properly
>   without JavaScript enabled. If you can't enable JavaScript try
>   visiting the mobile-optimized website. "

Now what i'm trying to do is, if anyone disable JavaScript, they will only be able to show a message, nothing else.
How can I do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to detect if JavaScript is disabled?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/121203/how-to-detect-if-javascript-is-disabled)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

this will redirect to javascriptNotEnabled.php

```
 <noscript><h3> You must have JavaScript enabled in order to use this order form. Please 
      enable JavaScript and then reload this page in order to continue. </h3> 
      <meta HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" content=0;url="javascriptNotEnabled.php"></noscript>
```

Comment: @yesitsme, it's working for me.  I have one doubt after enabling the script how to redirect on the previous page?

Comment: @user9437856 theres a up-vote button, I don't understand your question.

Comment: @yesitsme, For example, I am no homepage and  My script is disabled. Now I added your above code like   <noscript><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=javascript-disable.php" /></noscript> so that will redirect on javascript-disable.php page . Now I am on javascript-disable.php page after  I enable the script and refresh the page then how to redirect  from javascript-disable.php to homepage?

Comment: Yes, Sure I will do upvote.

Comment: you're probably looking for this https://stackoverflow.com/a/46498548/4535386

Answer (score 1):

### How??

What you should do is create a `div` that fills the entire page using `html` and `css`, then right after `window.onload`, remove that `div`

```
<div id="nojs" style="width:100%;height:100%;position:fixed; background-color:white;">
   <h1>Enable JavaScript!</h1>
</div>
<script>
   window.onload = function () {
       document.getElementById('nojs').parentElement.removeChild(document.getElementById('nojs'));
   }
</script>
```

`noscript` doesn't can't disable the *whole* page as far as I am concerned

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/7pnot5rx/) while JSFiddle doesn't work without JavaScript, the code still is an example

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a server-side and can't analyze such settings of your browser.

But, You can just use javascript `<noscript>` tag to do this

The `<noscript>` tag defines an alternate content for users that have disabled scripts in their browser or have a browser that doesn't support script.

Read more about `<noscript>` [from the w3 resource here](https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/noscript)

```
<script>
document.write("Hello World!")
</script>
<noscript>Please enable JavaScript!</noscript>
```

Answer (score 0):

load the site contents via javascript.

Your page should look like:

```
<html>
    <body>JavaScript Required We're sorry, but Facebook doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. If you can't enable JavaScript try visiting the mobile-optimized website.</body>
    <script>
        document.getElementByTagName("body").innerHTML = "";
    </script>
    <script src="loadPage.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: `getElementByTagName(...)` should be `getElementsByTagName(...)`