# HTML redirect on page load

Tags: javascript, html

I need one of my website pages to instantly redirect to another upon loading. The refresh HTML command does not work, as it does not check whether or not a certain url is being loaded. Also javascript will work too.

Comment: An example of what you have tried? So you want the page to load and then redirect or do you want an instant redirect?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirect from an HTML page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5411538/redirect-from-an-html-page)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I redirect to another webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-do-i-redirect-to-another-webpage)

Answer (score 45):

You can wait for a load [event](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_events.asp) with JavaScript and use one of either:

```
window.onload = function() {
    // similar behavior as clicking on a link
    window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
}
```

or

```
window.onload = function() {
    // similar behavior as an HTTP redirect
    window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");
}
```

Source: [How to redirect to another webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-to-redirect-to-another-webpage)

Answer (score 45):

Just add a `meta` tag in the `head` section of your `HTML` like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://redirect-to-this-page.com" />
    <title></title>
  </head>
 <body></body>
</html>
```

Comment: This answer is so good! How is it not more widely known!!