# Auto Click on hyperlink

Tags: javascript, html, click

I would like to a HTML code with the following functions if you guys can help , please.

Once the page loads, after 1 second to auto click on a hyperlinked text , how do I do this ? For the new website to be opened in the same window.

I have this code but this one is sending me to a new window and the pop up is blocking - not good

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<head>
<script>
function autoClick(){
document.getElementById('linkToClick').click();
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="setTimeout('autoClick();',700);">
<a id="linkToClick" href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">GOOGLE</a>
</body>


</body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Comment: Tried removing the `target="_blank"`?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `<a href=>` you should try just setting the variable `window.location.href`. So your code should look something like this:

```
<body onload="window.location.href='http://www.google.com',700);">
```

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_redirect_webpage.asp

Comment: Try `window.location` instead of `. href`

Answer (score 0):

Let me preface this by saying this is extremely questionable when it comes to web design, and generally regarded as a shady or bad practice. That said:

`$(window).on('load', function(){
     window.location = 'http://example.com'
});`

OR (vanilla JS)

`window.onload = function(){ window.location = 'http://example.com' };`

Again, be careful with this. If you want to do something like this, you need a pretty good reason why.

Possible duplicates:

[Redirect from an HTML page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5411538/redirect-from-an-html-page)

[HTML redirect on page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46498522/html-redirect-on-page-load)