# How to initialize the gallery on webpage load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, photoswipe

In the photoswipe documentation there's the code, which opens the gallery on the thumbnail click. What I am trying to do is to open the gallery (fist slide) on the webpage load.

I've tried to call openPhotoSwipe(); function from the different areas of the code, with index=0, I tried to modify the function itself, but I don't fully understand how the function works - so in every trial it just stops working. How to change the js code properly so it would open the galley on load of the webpage?

```html
<div class="my-gallery" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageGallery">

    <figure itemprop="associatedMedia" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
        <a href="large-image.jpg" itemprop="contentUrl" data-size="600x400">
            <img src="small-image.jpg" itemprop="thumbnail" alt="Image description" />
        </a>
        <figcaption itemprop="caption description">Image caption</figcaption>
    </figure>

    <figure itemprop="associatedMedia" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
        <a href="large-image.jpg" itemprop="contentUrl" data-size="600x400">
            <img src="small-image.jpg" itemprop="thumbnail" alt="Image description" />
        </a>
        <figcaption itemprop="caption description">Image caption</figcaption>
    </figure>


</div>
```

```js
var initPhotoSwipeFromDOM = function(gallerySelector) {

    // parse slide data (url, title, size ...) from DOM elements 
    // (children of gallerySelector)
    var parseThumbnailElements = function(el) {
        var thumbElements = el.childNodes,
            numNodes = thumbElements.length,
            items = [],
            figureEl,
            linkEl,
            size,
            item;

        for(var i = 0; i < numNodes; i++) {

            figureEl = thumbElements[i]; // <figure> element

            // include only element nodes 
            if(figureEl.nodeType !== 1) {
                continue;
            }

            linkEl = figureEl.children[0]; // <a> element

            size = linkEl.getAttribute('data-size').split('x');

            // create slide object
            item = {
                src: linkEl.getAttribute('href'),
                w: parseInt(size[0], 10),
                h: parseInt(size[1], 10)
            };



            if(figureEl.children.length > 1) {
                // <figcaption> content
                item.title = figureEl.children[1].innerHTML; 
            }

            if(linkEl.children.length > 0) {
                // <img> thumbnail element, retrieving thumbnail url
                item.msrc = linkEl.children[0].getAttribute('src');
            } 

            item.el = figureEl; // save link to element for getThumbBoundsFn
            items.push(item);
        }

        return items;
    };

    // find nearest parent element
    var closest = function closest(el, fn) {
        return el && ( fn(el) ? el : closest(el.parentNode, fn) );
    };

    // triggers when user clicks on thumbnail
    var onThumbnailsClick = function(e) {
        e = e || window.event;
        e.preventDefault ? e.preventDefault() : e.returnValue = false;

        var eTarget = e.target || e.srcElement;

        // find root element of slide
        var clickedListItem = closest(eTarget, function(el) {
            return (el.tagName && el.tagName.toUpperCase() === 'FIGURE');
        });

        if(!clickedListItem) {
            return;
        }

        // find index of clicked item by looping through all child nodes
        // alternatively, you may define index via data- attribute
        var clickedGallery = clickedListItem.parentNode,
            childNodes = clickedListItem.parentNode.childNodes,
            numChildNodes = childNodes.length,
            nodeIndex = 0,
            index;

        for (var i = 0; i < numChildNodes; i++) {
            if(childNodes[i].nodeType !== 1) { 
                continue; 
            }

            if(childNodes[i] === clickedListItem) {
                index = nodeIndex;
                break;
            }
            nodeIndex++;
        }



        if(index >= 0) {
            // open PhotoSwipe if valid index found
            openPhotoSwipe( index, clickedGallery );
        }
        return false;
    };

    // parse picture index and gallery index from URL (#&pid=1&gid=2)
    var photoswipeParseHash = function() {
        var hash = window.location.hash.substring(1),
        params = {};

        if(hash.length < 5) {
            return params;
        }

        var vars = hash.split('&');
        for (var i = 0; i < vars.length; i++) {
            if(!vars[i]) {
                continue;
            }
            var pair = vars[i].split('=');  
            if(pair.length < 2) {
                continue;
            }           
            params[pair[0]] = pair[1];
        }

        if(params.gid) {
            params.gid = parseInt(params.gid, 10);
        }

        return params;
    };

    var openPhotoSwipe = function(index, galleryElement, disableAnimation, fromURL) {
        var pswpElement = document.querySelectorAll('.pswp')[0],
            gallery,
            options,
            items;

        items = parseThumbnailElements(galleryElement);

        // define options (if needed)
        options = {

            // define gallery index (for URL)
            galleryUID: galleryElement.getAttribute('data-pswp-uid'),

            getThumbBoundsFn: function(index) {
                // See Options -> getThumbBoundsFn section of documentation for more info
                var thumbnail = items[index].el.getElementsByTagName('img')[0], // find thumbnail
                    pageYScroll = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop,
                    rect = thumbnail.getBoundingClientRect(); 

                return {x:rect.left, y:rect.top + pageYScroll, w:rect.width};
            }

        };

        // PhotoSwipe opened from URL
        if(fromURL) {
            if(options.galleryPIDs) {
                // parse real index when custom PIDs are used 
                // http://photoswipe.com/documentation/faq.html#custom-pid-in-url
                for(var j = 0; j < items.length; j++) {
                    if(items[j].pid == index) {
                        options.index = j;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                // in URL indexes start from 1
                options.index = parseInt(index, 10) - 1;
            }
        } else {
            options.index = parseInt(index, 10);
        }

        // exit if index not found
        if( isNaN(options.index) ) {
            return;
        }

        if(disableAnimation) {
            options.showAnimationDuration = 0;
        }

        // Pass data to PhotoSwipe and initialize it
        gallery = new PhotoSwipe( pswpElement, PhotoSwipeUI_Default, items, options);
        gallery.init();
    };

    // loop through all gallery elements and bind events
    var galleryElements = document.querySelectorAll( gallerySelector );

    for(var i = 0, l = galleryElements.length; i < l; i++) {
        galleryElements[i].setAttribute('data-pswp-uid', i+1);
        galleryElements[i].onclick = onThumbnailsClick;
    }

    // Parse URL and open gallery if it contains #&pid=3&gid=1
    var hashData = photoswipeParseHash();
    if(hashData.pid && hashData.gid) {
        openPhotoSwipe( hashData.pid ,  galleryElements[ hashData.gid - 1 ], true, true );
    }
};

// execute above function
initPhotoSwipeFromDOM('.my-gallery');
```

Comment: Maybe look for alternatives, for example, it would be quite easy accomplished using fancybox (http://fancyboxjs.com)

Answer (score 0):

Gotta wrap it in the jQuery document ready call...

```
$( document ).ready(function(){
  initPhotoSwipeFromDOM('.my-gallery');
})
```

Comment: This function initializes the overall js function which gets information from DOM, but it doesn't open the gallery...

Comment: I guess the openPhotoSwipe function in the code above opens the gallery putting info to "gallery = new PhotoSwipe( pswpElement, PhotoSwipeUI_Default, items, options);
gallery.init();". I just don't know how to call this function on load of the document, so it opened the gallery

Answer (score 0):

You could redirect, directly to the gallery unique URL.

Or, if you are linking to the gallery from somewhere else on your website just link to the gallery directly.

See answer on how to redirect: [HTML redirect on page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46498522/html-redirect-on-page-load)

And use your galleries unique address such as;
*mywebsite.com*/**#&gid=1&pid=1**