# Laravel 5 Javascript Enabled/Disabled Detection

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel, laravel-5

I should detect the browser supports Javascript or not in laravel 5.
As far as I know I have to use . But I am not sure which is the first php file which I can use in laravel 5?

Should I include it in public/index.php? It looks not correct.
Looking forward your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot do it with PHP. You can use the `<noscript>` tag in HTML.

Here is how you can do it:

```
<noscript>
  This page needs JavaScript activated to work.
</noscript>
```

If JS is not enabled, that code block in the HTML document will be executed. You can place that in your blade templates.

[`<noscript>` tag in w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_noscript.asp)

Comment: Where should I put this code snipped on laravel 5 project?
in public/index.php? that file contains only very basic include and i don't think it is a good place. which file can be a choice?

Answer (score 0):

This may be a duplicate of other questions regarding javascript detection you may find your answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121203/how-to-detect-if-javascript-is-disabled). From a google search I found something on github that may be of some use [link](https://github.com/hisorange/browser-detect). It seems to support checking for javascript support. It may be using the same technique found in the stackoverflow link I showed you.

The manual way can be done by redirecting to a cookie pickup like so

**index.php**

```
<?php

if(isset($_COOKIE["javascript_checked"]))
{
    $GLOBALS["javascript_enabled"] = isset($_COOKIE["javascript_enabled"]) ? true : false;
}
else
{
    setcookie("javascript_check_original_request", "http://" . $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], time()+3600);
    header("Location: http://" .  $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . "/detectjs.php.php");
    exit;
}


var_dump($GLOBALS["javascript_enabled"]); // prints out the result
```

**detectjs.php**

```
<?php
setcookie("javascript_checked", "true", time()+3600);
?>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;url=<?php echo $_COOKIE["javascript_check_original_request"]; ?>" />
<script type="text/javascript">

    /**
     * A function to simplify the process of creating a cookie
     * @param string name
     * @param string value
     * @param int days
     */
    function createCookie(name,value,days) {
        if (days)
        {
            var date = new Date();
            date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
            var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
        }
        else var expires = "";
        document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
    }
    createCookie("javascript_enabled", "true", 1); // creates a cookie that says javascript is enabled for 1 day
</script>
```

This will check for a cookie to see if the cookie pickup has happened, if it hasn't then it will redirect to a page that sets the cookie that the cookie pickup has happened and if javascript is enabled then the javascript will create a cookie that states it is enabled. it will then redirect back to the original request so that the user wouldn't notice a difference besides a second delay that it takes for the detectjs script to redirect back to the original request.

now that the check has been done, php can store a boolean into the $GLOBALS variable that contains a boolean for if javascript is enabled or not. You can reference this in any php file in laravel to make decisions if javascript is enabled or not using

```
if($GLOBALS["javascript_enabled"])
{

}
else
{

}
```

This can easily be done manually with the process above but if you want to use that laravel library I linked, more power to you.

Answer (score 0):

While you cannot rely on PHP by itself to detect whether Javascript is enabled, you can use Javascript to help to detect if Javascript is enabled.

### Set a Cookie with Javascript

Javascript can set cookies. Thus, if the user does not have the cookie, then it is a good indication that Javascript was not enabled. If the user does have the cookie, then the user probably have Javascript enabled. (Although you cannot be 100% sure.)

```
<script>
window.onload = function() {
    document.cookie = "hasjs=true";
}
</script>
```

Now you can use PHP to check whether the cookie exists.

```
if ($_COOKIE['hasjs'] == 'true') {
    // js enabled.
}
```

### Make an GET Request with Javascript

Javascript can also make [get requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247483/http-get-request-in-javascript). You can make a get request to a "hidden" php script. If the script never receives the get, then it is a good indication that Javascript was not enabled. If the script receives a get, then the user probably have Javascript enabled. (But again, you cannot be 100% sure.)

```
<script>
var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlHttp.open("GET", "/detectjs", true);
xmlHttp.send(null);
</script>
```

Once you receive the GET, you can note down that this user have javascript enabled for future references.