# Preloader JS Loading Gif Does Not Disappear if User Has Javascript Disabled

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is my simple loading gif JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

 $(window).load(function(){
    $('.doc-loader').fadeOut('slow');
 });
```

Class for loading gif div:

```
.doc-loader{
position: fixed;
left: 0;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
overflow: visible;
background: #ffffff url('../images/gears.gif') no-repeat center center;
z-index: 100000;
text-align: center;
padding-top: 535px;
}
```

If the user has Javascript disabled, the users cannot access the page because the loading gif does not go away (in the CSS the height/width of the div is 100%)

Is there a way to only show my preloader div if the user has Javascript enabled?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect if JavaScript is disabled?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/121203/how-to-detect-if-javascript-is-disabled)

Comment: Not quite the same question, although is relevant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get it to work using the following code:

```
<head>
    <noscript>
        <style>#doc-loader { display: none }</style>
    </noscript>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="doc-loader" id="doc-loader"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `<noscript>` section to put a css rule to hide your loading screen and unhide your normal content. `noscript` in header blocks is valid HTML5.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#main {display: none };
</style>
<noscript>
<style>
#loader { display: none; }
#main { display: block; }
</style>
</noscript>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="loader">
    <p>This is the loader...</p>
  </div>
  <div id="main">
    <p>Main content</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

**Edit:** Above works in latest Firefox, try other browsers. Expect it will work in browsers that support HTML5, may be problems with old browers.

Comment: Cool, I'll try updating that. Any idea if I can do this via my css sheet instead of inlining it?

Comment: I'm at work and don't have time to try anything. I'd appreciate it if you post your own answer if you get it to work :)

Comment: Checked above script works in latest Firefox, have't time to test all situations

Comment: I was able to get it to work using the following code:
    <head>
    <noscript><style>#doc-loader { display: none }</style></noscript>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="doc-loader" id="doc-loader"></div>
    </body>