# Detect whether client system is Laptop or Desktop using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to show the **battery status of client's system and a clock** in a widget in my webpage **If it is a Laptop**.
If it is a desktop, I don't want to show the battery status.
The clock widget is working fine.

Also I am able to get the battery details by using `navigator.getBattery()`.
But if it is Desktop, I don't want to show the widget.

**So, How to detect whether the client using Desktop or Laptop using JavaScript**?

The below is the contents of `navigator` but it didn't have details to detect whether it is a Laptop or Desktop.

```js
console.log(navigator);
```

```
{
  "vendorSub": "",
  "productSub": "20030107",
  "vendor": "Google Inc.",
  "maxTouchPoints": 0,
  "hardwareConcurrency": 4,
  "appCodeName": "Mozilla",
  "appName": "Netscape",
  "appVersion": "5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36",
  "platform": "Win32",
  "product": "Gecko",
  "userAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36",
  "language": "en-GB",
  "languages": [
    "en-US",
    "en"
  ],
  "onLine": true,
  "cookieEnabled": true,
  "doNotTrack": null,
  "geolocation": {
    "getCurrentPosition": function getCurrentPosition() { [native code] },
    "watchPosition": function watchPosition() { [native code] },
    "clearWatch": function clearWatch() { [native code] }
  },
  "mediaDevices": {
    "enumerateDevices": function enumerateDevices() { [native code] },
    "getSupportedConstraints": function getSupportedConstraints() { [native code] },
    "getUserMedia": function getUserMedia() { [native code] },
    "addEventListener": function addEventListener() { [native code] },
    "removeEventListener": function removeEventListener() { [native code] },
    "dispatchEvent": function dispatchEvent() { [native code] }
  },
  "plugins": {
    "0": [object Plugin],
    "1": [object Plugin],
    "2": [object Plugin],
    "3": [object Plugin],
    "4": [object Plugin],
    "length": 5,
    "item": function item() { [native code] },
    "namedItem": function namedItem() { [native code] },
    "refresh": function refresh() { [native code] }
  },
  "mimeTypes": {
    "0": [object MimeType],
    "1": [object MimeType],
    "2": [object MimeType],
    "3": [object MimeType],
    "4": [object MimeType],
    "5": [object MimeType],
    "6": [object MimeType],
    "length": 7,
    "item": function item() { [native code] },
    "namedItem": function namedItem() { [native code] }
  },
  "webkitTemporaryStorage": {
    "queryUsageAndQuota": /**id:16**/ function queryUsageAndQuota() { [native code] },
    "requestQuota": /**id:17**/ function requestQuota() { [native code] }
  },
  "webkitPersistentStorage": {
    "queryUsageAndQuota": /**ref:16**/,
    "requestQuota": /**ref:17**/
  },
  "serviceWorker": /**error accessing property**/,
  "getBattery": function getBattery() { [native code] },
  "sendBeacon": function sendBeacon() { [native code] },
  "requestMediaKeySystemAccess": function requestMediaKeySystemAccess() { [native code] },
  "getGamepads": function getGamepads() { [native code] },
  "webkitGetUserMedia": function webkitGetUserMedia() { [native code] },
  "javaEnabled": function javaEnabled() { [native code] },
  "vibrate": function vibrate() { [native code] },
  "requestMIDIAccess": function requestMIDIAccess() { [native code] },
  "credentials": {
    "get": function get() { [native code] },
    "store": function store() { [native code] },
    "requireUserMediation": function requireUserMediation() { [native code] }
  },
  "storage": {
    "persisted": function persisted() { [native code] },
    "persist": function () { [native code] }
  },
  "permissions": {
    "query": function query() { [native code] }
  },
  "presentation": {
    "defaultRequest": null
  },
  "getUserMedia": function getUserMedia() { [native code] },
  "registerProtocolHandler": function registerProtocolHandler() { [native code] },
  "unregisterProtocolHandler": function unregisterProtocolHandler() { [native code] }
}
```

Comment: You can use [the Battery API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Battery_Status_API) to get the status, but you can't tell whether the device is a desktop or laptop.

Comment: There is no way to identify a device as a laptop / desktop machine.

Comment: @Pointy - `From Firefox 52 onwards, the Battery Status API is only available in chrome/privileged code`

Comment: why would I go to your website to see the time and my battery status, I can see both perfectly well without running my browser

Comment: I am able to get the battery level in Plain JavaScript. But i want to hide the widget if it is a desktop.

Comment: If you try it on a desktop presumably its 0 or undefined? That's your identifier if so

Comment: @JaromandaX I am building a Web based OS in javascript running in browser. So, these are widgets

Comment: According to some other documentation I've seen, if there's no battery at all then the level is reported as 1 and "charging" as `true`.

Comment: _If you try it on a desktop presumably its 0 or undefined?_ @DarrenSweeney I tried it on lap only. are you sure about this?

Comment: Ok, I just had a quick look on a desktop... it says battery charging: `true`, charging time (`battery.chargingTime`): 0 - these never change regardless of time gone - so that combination would (probably) tell you it's not a laptop? - here's a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/2943xx9j/

Comment: [wurfl](https://web.wurfl.io/#wurfl-js) could be help you done this.

Comment: @DarrenSweeney Thanks  a lot brother. please consider making an answer for future visitors.

Comment: @SagarV will do it now

Comment: perhaps including `Battery charging time: 0 seconds`  and `Battery discharging time: Infinity seconds` is also pretty much a giveaway @DarrenSweeney

Comment: @holi-java it is an Interesting one.

Comment: thanks @JaromandaX will try

Comment: @JaromandaX yeah, I'd think that too but comment under answer makes me wonder, I haven't got laptop to try unfortunately

Comment: expect comment from downvoters

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect if JavaScript is disabled?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/121203/how-to-detect-if-javascript-is-disabled)

Comment: @monstro from the title itself it is clear that this is not what I want.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As mentioned in comments - it's possible to get charging status (true/false) `battery.charging` and charging time (in seconds) `battery.chargingTime` from the Battery API

On a desktop the charging is always `true` but charging time is always `0`

This allows us to determine it's a desktop

Here's a quick snippet to test if desktop...

```js
navigator.getBattery().then(function(battery) {
    if (battery.charging && battery.chargingTime === 0) {
        console.log("I'm a desktop")
    } else {
        console.log("I'm not a desktop")
    }
});
```

**Note**

This is not an exact science. As @MatheusAvellar pointed out. My guess is if you're fully charged although `battery.charging` may be true, `battery.chargingTime` may then go to 0 - don't have access to laptop to try

Comment: It's good to point out that his won't _always_ work. I'm on a plugged in laptop with 100% charge, and the code says I'm a desktop. Whatever it is you want to do with this, keep in mind that it won't be always accurate.

Comment: this is not working in IE. navigator.getBattery is undefined.

Comment: Note that this is limited in terms of browser support: https://caniuse.com/?search=battery e.g. no IE, Firefox, or Safari support.  There's also a `battery.level` value that may (when it shows a number less than 99) better indicate a laptop... when plugged in my laptop never gets above 99% charged... but a 45% battery would be a dead giveaway that it is a *portable* device.

Comment: The fact that they made getBattery() a promise simply overcomplicates it?! Or does it have any effect on subordinated events? Bye bye simple if clause...