# How do I check and inform user had javascript enabled in browser

Tags: javascript, html

My desktop application creates a html report at the end showing results and opens it in users default webbrowser. The report is in html5 and utilises a frameset, clicking items on the left hand frame changes the display on the right handside.

But one for one user it didn't work because they had NoScript add on installed which I think by default disables Javascript.

What is the accepted way to inform users they need Javascript enabled, can the report itself proactively identify whether Javascript has been disabled (for the report).

Comment: This might be helpful [This link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/121203/how-to-detect-if-javascript-is-disabled)

Comment: @Nicholas - yes it is. That is why the question is closed as duplicate

Comment: why don't they search on Google before posting QQ

Comment: @Nicholas you could have removed the space between ] and ( then only the link work. Bad luck. It is already more than 5 mins

Comment: @SagarV, well things happen :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `<noscript>` tag which will be shown only if Javascript disabled:

`<noscript> App can't run without JavaScript</noscript>`

Comment: It was faster to find a duplicate and close than to write code. You could have done the same

Comment: @mplungjan I did search and came across noscript but the answers seemed to be about providing a javascript free version of the webpage, that was not feasible in my case, they did not address how to inform to the user that there was an issue. Also I thought there might be a standard way to inform user but it appears there is not really.