# How can you check if Javascript is executed on the system?

Tags: javascript

Each browser has some kind of console for debugging and tracing Javascript.
But is there some way to do tracing below the browser, like on the operating system level? Or at least some way to determine if Javascript is executed at all in the browser (or maybe other applications too) ?

Edit: 
This was linked to [How to detect if JavaScript is disabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121203/how-to-detect-if-javascript-is-disabled)
but is in no way related. The linked question deals with server side detection if Javascript is enabled on the client.
I'd like to know more or less the opposite. From within the browser it seems to be trivial but there does not seem to be a way from the outside. 
I was thinking about something like tracing the whole browser or maybe there are some artifacts in RAM which would be a giveaway.

Comment: The javascript is executed within each browser's rendering engine. I have never heard of any tools that can read the js console externally like that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect if JavaScript is disabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121203/how-to-detect-if-javascript-is-disabled)

Comment: Not a duplicate. My question asks for the opposite case.

Comment: If you detect that it is not disabled then it is executed. Or am I wrong?

Comment: You should better specify environmental info... Where is your detection code supposed to be run? On the client's OS? Is so, the first problem I see is to detect which is the the browser do investigate, they could be less or mre than one, for example...

Comment: @MrMaavin Well, sort of correct. But I'd like to know if it is there at all. If yes, does it do anything and ideally what it does. js can also be sometimes hidden in images so it is not always straightforward to spot.  MarcoS, Code should run on the OS, or at least not in the browser. Lets say we only have one browser, then how would you do it?