# How to invoke Onclick in Anchor tag only if JavaScript if enabled, in case if Javascript is disabled then execute href?

Tags: javascript, html, anchor

How can I invoke Onclick in Anchor tag only if JavaScript if enabled, in case if Javascript is disabled then execute href?

Comment: what do you mean by `execute href` ?

Comment: I think te OnClick will only get executed when javascript is enabled by default. How can it be executed when javascript is disabled?

Comment: If you want to execute a js function when js is disabled then it can't be done. But you can achieve the task performed by js function by using php in `<noscript>`

Comment: Sure, actually my requirement is to call a URL which should only invoke when JavaScript is disabled, else Java script function should get executed. 
Example:
<a href="TestURL" onclick="myFunction()">TestLink</a>
Please let me know in case if more explanation needed.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

kindly elaborate why do you want to check for java-script disable for executing href.
For checking java-script disable you can refer below link for your reference.

[How to detect if JavaScript is disabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121203/how-to-detect-if-javascript-is-disabled)

**Edit:** if javascript is disabled then function written in html will fail automatically and href will gets executed. Please check with below code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<script>
document.write("Hello World!")
function test()
{
alert('okoko');
return false;
}

</script>
<noscript>Sorry, your browser does not support JavaScript!</noscript>

<a href="http://google.com" onclick="return test();">test</a>
<p onclick="">A browser without support for JavaScript will show the text inside the noscript element.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

as per above screenshots it is confirm that href will gets executed automatically when java-script is disabled.

Hope this answer will help you.

Comment: Thanks Vikas, actually I am aware of <noscript> tag. 
But my requirement is to call a URL which should only invoke when JavaScript is disabled, else Java script function should get executed. Example: <a href="TestURL" onclick="myFunction()">TestLink</a> 

TestURL should only get executed when JS is disabled, else myFunction() ONLY should invoked. 

Please let me know in case if more explanation needed.

Comment: Thank you Vikas. It worked. I tried same but only thing I missed was "return" inside onclick function.

Answer (score 1):

The JavaScript can only run if JavaScript is enabled.

The href will be followed automatically when a link is clicked on (that's the *default* behaviour) *unless* JavaScript is used to prevent it.

```js
function onClick(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log("JavaScript function called");
}
const link = document.querySelector("a");
link.addEventListener("click", onClick);
```

```html
<a href="http://example.com/">Link</a>
```