# Display different content for javascript enabled users and different content for javascript disabled users on the same page in Mediawiki?

Tags: html, css, mediawiki

I placed this code `.scriptonly { display: none; }` in Mediawiki:Noscript.css and then used `<div class="scriptonly">Content </div>` on my page and the content displays only for javascript enabled users.

How do i do same for users who have javascript disabled?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect if JavaScript is disabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121203/how-to-detect-if-javascript-is-disabled)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<noscript>` tag

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_noscript.asp

Comment: <noscript> tag works on mediawiki only if i place ```$wgRawHtml=true``` in my LocalSettings.php file. Do you know of any other alternative?

Answer (score 0):

`<noscript>` isn't even necessary, and it **is not supported in XHTML**

You can initially set the class to `.scriptonly{display:none;}`.
Then you can add fillowing code, which will only be executed if user has enabled javascript, otherwise it will be ignored. You can toggle style properties if desired.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     document.querySelectorAll(".scriptonly").style.display="block";
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hide element `#foo` from clients which have javascript:

```
html.client-js #foo { display: hidden; }
```

Hide element `#foo` from clients which do not have javascript:

```
html.client-nojs #foo { display: hidden; }
```