# How to get a single row data from a jquery datatable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I render data from a Mysql database to a clientside browser using a php script with `jquery` Datatables.  When a user clicks an Update button inside the Edit column, I want to take the cell value of the row and fill a form so the user can update the information.  The main problem is the `jquery` `on.('click', 'button', function)` does not want to get the `table.row` data.  The on click function is working though.

I have tried:

php script that renders the table:

```
<table id="usert"  class="display" style="width:100%">
                <thead>
                    <th>Id</th>
                    <th>User</th>
                    <th>Usernames</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <th>Employee</th>
                    <th>Product</th>
                    <th>Admin</th>
                    <th>Active</th>
                    <th>Edit</th>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <?php
                        //Select all users names from database and populate the select tag
                        include_once './db/dbconnect.php';
                        include_once './db/website/dbfunc_web.php';
                        $db = connectBlind();
                        $users_i = findUsers($db);
                        $cnt = 0;
                        if ($users_i != false) {
                            foreach ($users_i as $key => $value) {
                                $cnt ++;
                                echo "<tr>";
                                echo "<td>".$cnt."</td>";
                                echo "<td>".$key."</td>";
                                foreach ($value as $key => $val) {
                                    if ($key === 'emp_priv' || $key === 'prod_priv' || $key === 'admin_priv' || $key === 'active') {
                                        if ($val === 1) {
                                            echo "<td>Yes</td>";
                                        } else {
                                            echo "<td>No</td>";
                                        }
                                    } else {
                                        echo "<td>".$val."</td>";
                                    }

                                }
                                echo "<td><button style="."'background-color: #3CB371; border: none; color: white; font-size: 14px; padding: 8px 10px; border-radius: 8px;'".">Update</button></td>";
                                echo "</tr>";
                            }
                        }
                    ?>
```

jquery functions:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
            $('#usert').DataTable();
        });

        $('#usert tbody').on( 'click', 'button', function () {
            var data = table.row( $(this).parents('tr') ).data();
            window.alert( data[1]);
        } );
```

I want to get the single `table.row` data of the specific Update button clicked?

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: @Nidhin Joseph I expect to get the user, username, email and privileges from the row, which would be the following elements in the data Array data[1], data[2], data[3], data[4], data[5] and data[6].  The above example only outputs the user as an alert popup for testing purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the `<tr>` using the `closest()` and then the `get()` to get each index.

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  let td = $(this).closest('tr').find('td');
  let result = {
    id: td.get(0).innerText,
    user: td.get(1).innerText,
    username: td.get(2).innerText
  };
  console.log(result)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<table>
  <thead>
    <th>Id</th>
    <th>User</th>
    <th>Usernames</th>
    <th>Edit</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Jon</td>
      <td>jon_bob</td>
      <td><button>Edit</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>bob</td>
      <td>bob_jon</td>
      <td><button>Edit</button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you very much!  It works great.  Will this work if a user disables javascript in their browser?

Comment: jQuery is a cross-platform JavaScript library. So, if JS is disabled, it won't work.

Comment: Okay, I suspected as much.  I know this was not part of my original question, but do you know of back-up solutions for in case a user has disabled JavaScript?

Comment: there isn't a fallback method to make your application work. Just have a read into this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121203/how-to-detect-if-javascript-is-disabled

Comment: I know this comment will probably be deleted, but thank you for your help.